# Как из массива отнять n-нное количество элементов

Tags: java, массивы, intellij-idea

Есть 100 коробок.

Необходимо Вычесть из массива n-нное количество проданных коробок.

Возникла проблема с реализацией, не понятно как отнять из общего числа коробок n-ное количество

```java
public class Magazine {

    Box[] boxes = new Box[100];
    private int money;

    private void sales(int money, Box[] boxes) {
        this.boxes = boxes;
        this.money = money;
        //... тут мне надо отнять из общего кол-во коробок 5 и получить за них деньги
    }
}

public class Box {

    public Box(int quantity, Fish fish) {
        this.quantity = quantity;
        this.fish = fish;
    }

    private int quantity; // Количество рыбы
    private Fish fish; // Сама рыба в коробке


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В вашем случае лучше использовать `ArrayList` это не массив, а структура, у которой есть методы `add` и `remove` для добавления и удаления объектов из структуры.

```
 ArrayList <Box> listOfBoxes = new ArrayList<>();
 // Добавляем на "склад 100 коробок"
 for (int i = 0; i<100; i++){
 Box box = new Box()l
 listOfBoxes.add(box);
 }

 // при продаже коробок с рыбой

 for (int i =0; i<5;i++){
 listOfBoxes.remove(i);
 // после продажи в списке коробок уже 95 коробок
 }
```

Comment: Да, через коллекции было бы интереснее и легче, но дело в том, что задача стоит именно с массивами.

Answer (score 1):

Можно при продаже нескольких ящиков сделать размерность массива меньше.
Например:
Если есть 100 ящиков, и продаем 5 коробок, то размерность уменьшается на 5.

```java
public class Magazine {

    Box[] boxes = new Box[100];
    private int money;
    private int n; // Количество продаваемых коробок

    private void sales(int money, Box[] boxes) {
        this.boxes = boxes;
        this.money = money;
        boxes = new Box[100 - n];
    }
```

Не знаю почему сразу не догадался. Тупил долго.

Comment: Больше похоже на костыль, чем на решение, если задуматься о будущем, то как вести отчёт по такой структуре ?

Comment: Согласен, без коллекций все выглядит как костыль

Answer (score 1):

Лучшим и наиболее дальновидным способом будет использование ArrayList, так как он, по сути, содержит в себе массив. А все методы уже написаны за вас.

```
class Magazine {
    ArrayList<Box> boxes = new ArrayList<Box>(100);
    private int money;

    Magazine(Box[] boxes){
        addNewBoxes(boxes);
    }

    private void toSale(int money, Box[] boxes) throws IOException {
        ArrayList<Box> toSale = (ArrayList<Box>) Arrays.stream(boxes).collect(Collectors.toList());
        ArrayList<Box> boxesWeDontHave = new ArrayList<>();
        for(Box boxToSale : toSale) { // можно улучшить, но понятности ради...
            boolean haveWeBoxToSale = false;
            for(int i = 0; i < this.boxes.size(); i++) {
                if(boxToSale.equals(this.boxes.get(i))) {
                    haveWeBoxToSale = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if(!haveWeBoxToSale) {
                boxesWeDontHave.add(boxToSale);
            }
        }
        if(!boxesWeDontHave.isEmpty()) { // есть ли у нас 
            this.boxes.removeAll(Arrays.stream(boxes).collect(Collectors.toList()));
            this.money += money;
        } else {
            String error = "We dont have these boxes: ";
            for(int i = 0; i < boxesWeDontHave.size() - 1; i++) {
                error += boxesWeDontHave.get(i).toString() + ", ";
            }
            error += boxesWeDontHave.get(boxesWeDontHave.size() - 1).toString() + ".";
            throw new IOException(error); //можете сами создать исключение
        }
    }

    void addNewBoxes(Box[] boxes) {
        this.boxes.addAll(Arrays.stream(boxes).collect(Collectors.toList()));
    }
}
```